# Parallel STL algorithms execution in C++17

Tags: c++, algorithm, parallel-processing, stl, c++17

Studying about parallelism in stl functions in c++17, I am wondering what is the underlying synchronisation mechanism that is used.
For example , have a look in the following piece of [code](https://godbolt.org/z/Ge3PTrxe4)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <execution>
#include <mutex>
int GenRandom(size_t lower, size_t upper) 
{
    // usage of thread local random engines allows running the generator in concurrent mode
    thread_local static std::default_random_engine rd;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dist(lower, upper);
    return dist(rd);
}

int main()
{
        std::vector<double> vec(20, 0.5);
        std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), []() { return GenRandom(1,10); });
        std::vector out(vec);
        for(auto const &elem : out)
        {
            std::cout << elem << ",";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        std::transform(std::execution::par, vec.begin(), vec.end(), out.begin(),
            [](double v) {
            return v*2.0;
        });
        for(auto const &elem : out)
        {
            std::cout << elem << ",";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
        out.clear();
        std::mutex m;
        std::for_each(std::execution::par,vec.begin(),vec.end(),
            [&out,&m](auto&& item)
            {
                const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
                out.emplace_back(item*2);
            });
        for(auto const &elem : out)
        {
            std::cout << elem << ",";
        }
}
```

How is it ensured that no synchronisation issue will not arise when elements are inserted in vector out.
On the other hand, doing transformation using for_each synchronisation is needed

Comment: Because you're not inserting elements. Each thread modifies unrelated existing elements.

Comment: Are elements not inserted in container out?

Comment: @getsoubl Yes, by `std::transform` so it can use whatever synchronization primitives it likes internally. In `for_each` it's you who inserts so you need to sync it.

Comment: This is my question. That means  that depends on the implementation of the transfom or the other stl algorithms

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::transform` doesn't insert elements. It overwrites existing elements.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, `insert` was a bad word - but the problem would be similar if many threads wrote to the same elements at the same time

Comment: I think resizing `out` in advance removes any need for syncrhonization? `std::transform` is just glorified `for_each`.

Comment: If `std::transform(std::execution::par,` uses a thread pool to perform the transformation, it'd need to collect the result from each thread I guess. That's one form of synchronization

Comment: @getsoubl "_That means that depends on the implementation of the transfom or the other stl algorithms_" - Yes, all implementations of the standard library will likely do things differently in order to be conformant. All implementations I've used have been using Intel TBB internally.

Comment: @TedLyngmo MSVC STL uses Windows thread pool internally.

Comment: @Genjutsu Oh, I was sure they used TBB (at least previously, but that may be wrong too). The MSVC implementation was the first I tried with execution policies and it was brutal.

Comment: Your `std::transform` and `std::for_each` examples are doing very different things. `std::transform` assigns to existing elements of the vector; this is safe without synchronization as long as no two threads touch the same element. Whereas `for_each` example modifies the vector itself, by adding elements to it; this needs synchronization. If the callback passed to `for_each` did something like `out[&item - &vec[0]] = item*2;`, with the same net effect as the transform, it wouldn't have needed synchronization either.

Comment: In other words, synchronization is needed because the user-provided callback does something thread-unsafe, not because the STL algorithm does.